# How do I resolve the error "unrecognized options: --enable-password-save" when building openvpn under alpine linux?

Tags: docker, openvpn, alpine-linux

I am building a custom `openvpn` client within a `Docker` container that is based on a standard `node-alpine` image.

The (trimmed) docker image looks like:

```
FROM node:8.4-alpine
MAINTAINER: Dave <redacted@redacted.redacted>

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    file \
    make \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    python \
    wget

# install openVPN

RUN wget https://swupdate.openvpn.org/community/releases/openvpn-2.4.3.tar.gz --no-check-certificate
RUN gunzip openvpn-2.4.3.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf openvpn-2.4.3.tar

WORKDIR openvpn-2.4.3
RUN ./configure --enable-password-save
RUN make
RUN make install

# ... the rest of the file
```

When I build this I get an error

```
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-password-save
```

then the checks continue for a while before failing at

```
checking whether TUNSETPERSIST is declared... no
configure: error: no tap header could be found
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you got and the error in the configure script are unrelated.

The warning is just indicating the flag you passed is not valid, while the error means you are missing a dependency in your build path.

In this specific case you are missing the `tap` header. You need to install the `linux-headers` package.

By the way, you are also missing some other openVPN build dependencies:

- openssl-dev
- lzo-dev
- linux-pam-dev

To summarize, you need to edit the third command of your Dockerfile as follows:

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    file \
    make \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    python \
    wget \
    linux-headers \
    openssl-dev \
    lzo-dev \
    linux-pam-dev
```

And you should be good to go

Comment: thanks. that is working now. Weirdly if I drop the `--enable-password-save` flag then run `openvpn --version|grep enable_password_save` I get nothing. But with the flag, even though the warning comes up that the flag is invalid, `openvpn --version|grep enable_password_save` shows `enable_password_save="yes"`.